# how to redirect on a page in asp.net fom folder?

Tags: html, asp.net, redirect

I have web project "myweb.com" .it contains a folder "admin". So I want when I open a link it should open a login page. 
For e.g. when I open link www.myweb.com/admin/ then it must be redirected on this link www.myweb.com/admin/login.aspx.kindly help me. I am new in web development.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("~/admin") + "login.aspx");
```

Comment: Nice answer Rasool joon!

Answer (score 0):

Check if user is authenticated then redirect if not....

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
        {
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }
    }
```

If you don't specify a page then you need to do so in IIS otherwise you will get a 404 page not found error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. First way is using a link button then using the Repsonse.Redirect. Here it is shown below.

**Code Behind**

```
protected void lbLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/admin/login.aspx");
        }
```

**ASP**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="lbLinkButton_Click">Login</asp:LinkButton>
```

Or you can just have the PostBackUrl in the ASP control as well... like so...

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbLinkButton" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/admin/login.aspx">Login</asp:LinkButton>
```

Or you can use a Hyperlink like this..

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlHyperlink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/admin/login.aspx">Login</asp:HyperLink>
```

I hope this comes in handy!